# Nexus support for api.typings.org

Tags: nexus, typescript-typings

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins CI environment which is behind a corporate firewall and is also using Nexus to proxy repositories. Changing the firewall settings is not an option, but Nexus is able to bypass the firewall so I need to set up Nexus to be able to pull in type definition files. Is that possible?

A Google search turns up very little, besides [this support ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10976) which hasn't been answered.

Is it at all possible to add typings support to Nexus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typings is not on our roadmap yet, but as you can see someone has expressed interest. Feel free to pop in to that ticket and let your voice be heard, we use those to get a bit of a gauge to how many of our users are looking for a specific format.